# Ubuntu fails to boot fsck

Tags: boot, lubuntu, fsck

I have searched and searched, and I cannot seem to find the help I'm looking for. Before you say "yes this problem has been answered", please point me in the right direction.

I recently was gifted an old dell mini 9 with the 8GB SSD. I've installed lubuntu 16.04. This is my first experience with linux, so please be gentle with the instructions. When I boot I get stuck on the black screen that says 
/dev/sda1 clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks

I am able to boot to recovery, and continue normal boot to get to the os, but I don't know how to fix the issue. I tried changing the fstab 1 to 0, that didn't fix anything. I don't mind reinstalling as it's a clean install, but I've already tried that twice and it hasn't fixed the issue either. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What does it have to do with fsck?

Comment: To be honest I have no idea. I've been researching and googling this issue for a couple days now. Like I said, I'm a new linux user. I'm an experienced windows user, but what I found through google is that that dev/sda1 clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks is an output from fsck. If that's not my issue, great. I found another site that said run sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel, so after I fixed my wifi I tried that, and now OS does boot, but the black screen with that printout still pops up, so I'm not sure that I've fixed the underlying problem. I just don't know.

Comment: I don't see any underlying problems related to fsck. That line is not an error, but a rather regular filesystem check. It should have been covered by the splashscreen, but wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

if you have problem with sdb1 , means your sb1 is corrupted , 
so delete sb1 info from /etc/fstab and run

**sudo systemctl reboot**

(you dont need sudo if u are  accessing just as  root user,and this command will reboot your laptop,pc or whatev)
and it should work fine . 
that worked for me  :)